# OPSHub Branches Converted to Folders After migration

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

After using OPSHub to migrate to projects to Visual Studio Team Services (source code only) the "branches" only show up as folders. Is this expected? Do we need to manually convert to branches and re-parent?

[image: Branches before and after]

Comment: What version are you using? In the newer version of OVSMU, this has been enabled by default. Otherwise, you will have to open 'C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Migration Utility\Other_Resources\Resources\TFSUtility\TFSService\opshubtfsservice.exe.config' in a text editor, Search for the key 'CONVERT_TO_BRANCHOBJECT' and set it's value to true before running the migration.

Comment: I have version 1.0.  which version should I have please?

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the most recent version but seems to still be 1.0?  Maybe I should be referring to the integration manager framework version which is 2.0.0.0005?

Comment: The latest version is 2.0.0.005, you can download it from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2

Comment: Can you verify what the current value of the 'CONVERT_TO_BRANCHOBJECT' key is at the location mentioned above, for your installed application?

Comment: Thanks, yes I can verify it's there.  I have set it to "true" as I am unsure the application will do it by default.  Seems not, as it was set to false?

Comment: Yep, that is correct. Branch Icon will be set only if the flag is true.

Comment: So now we have migrated another project up and some, but not all of the branches were created??